# How to configure Grunt with ASP.NET WebApi Project?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, gruntjs

I am new to grunt and i want to use this with my current Asp.Net WebApi Single Page Application. For that purpose i want to know how we can configure Grunt with ASP.NET Project..

I am using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify your problem.

Google knows tons of article about Grunt in VS 2013/2015.

- [Introducing Gulp, Grunt, Bower, and npm support for Visual Studio](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx)
- [Grunt Launcher](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcbc5325-79ef-4b72-960e-0a51ee33a0ff)
- [Task Runner Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708)
- [Using Grunt, Gulp and Bower in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1096)
- [Configure Grunt in Visual Studio 2015](http://ardalis.com/configure-grunt-in-visual-studio-2015)
- and so on.

Try to use anything from these and will specify your problem if you still have it.

Answer (score 1):

**To Install Grunt**

> solution > right click > add > new item > npm Configuration file >
>   paste following code > save > be patient until it installs

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
    "bower": "1.7.9"
  }
}
```

**To Configure Grunt**

> solution > right click > add > new item > Grunt Configuration file >
>   paste following code > save

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    //load whatever you need here
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    //Task configuration is specified in your Gruntfile via this method
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    'wwwroot/app.js': ['scripts/app.js', 'scripts/**/*,']
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            script:{
                files: ['scripts/**/*,'],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }

        }
    });
    //register your tasks here(taskName,taskList)
    grunt.task.registerTask('task-minified', ['uglify', 'watch'])

};
```

**To Test Grunt**

> View > Other Windows > Task Runner Explorer

[image]